# trying to return values by comparing two columns from two different datasets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I have two racing kart datasets with 9 columns:

df1:

[image: df1 dataset]

df2:
[image: df2 dataset]

I am trying to set up multiple conditions where two datasets are compared and trying to print out True or false if the conditions are satisfying after comparing. the conditions are:

1. race_start (df1) <= race_start (df2)
2. race_end (df1) >= race_end(df2)
3. safety_start(df1) <= safety_start (df2)
4. safety_end (df1) >= safety_end (df2)
5. starting_front (df1) <= starting_front (df2)
6. starting_back (df1) <= starting_back (df2)
7. pitstop (df1) >= pitstop (df2)
8. no_pitstop (df1) >= no_pitstop (df2)
9. status (df1) = status (df2).

first, I tried this:

```
import numpy as np
df1['race_start_final'] = np.where(df1.race_start <= df2.race_start, 'True', 'False')
df1['race_end_final'] = np.where(df1.race_end >= df2.race_end, 'True', 'False')
df1['safety_start_final'] = np.where(df1.safety_start <= df2.safety_start, 'True', 'False')
df1['safety_end_final'] = np.where(df1.safety_end >= df2.safety_end, 'True', 'False')
df1['starting_front_final'] = np.where(df1.starting_front <= df2.starting_front, 'True', 'False')
df1['starting_back_final'] = np.where(df1.starting_back <= df2.starting_back, 'True', 'False')
df1['pitstop_final'] = np.where(df1.pitstop >= df2.pitstop, 'True', 'False')
df1['pitstop_final'] = np.where(df1.pitstop >= df2.pitstop, 'True', 'False')
df1['status_final'] = np.where(df1.status == df2.status, 'True', 'False')
```

but I got an error saying:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Am I doing it right? I tried finding alternate solutions but didn't find any relevant for what I am trying to do? Can anyone tell me if the procedure I chose is the right way? Thanks

Comment: 1. Please paste your dataframe as text in the question. 2. Please paste the full error.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you attempt to compare two pandas DataFrames and either the index labels or the column labels do not perfectly match or it has different dimension.

You can truncate DataFrames before where function with if-else statement:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    [10.5, 8.5],
    [8.5, 8.5]],
    columns=['race_start','race_end'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    [9.8, 9.8],
    [9.8, 9.8],
    [8.5, 8.5]],
    columns=['race_start','race_end'])

if len(df1) > len(df2):
    df1=df1.tail(df2.shape[0]).reset_index()
else:
    df2=df2.tail(df1.shape[0]).reset_index()
    
df1['race_start_final'] = np.where(df1.race_start <= df2.race_start, 'True', 'False')
```